# How many certificates used when sign-encrypt-signing emails?

Tags: smime

Would it be acceptable in a sign-encrypt-sign (email) setup to use the same certificate for both sign operations or should one opt for two separate certificates?
The encrypt operation is performed using the intended recipients public certificate.

Best regards,
Brian

Comment: Why do you want to sign this email after a first sign-encrypt operation?

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-sign-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-sign

Comment: Thanks, I know this thread, this is why I asked, because in this thread, somebody said *in practice, both are not enough*, but he has not given any explanation (I think there is none) => see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, before directly answering your question, I need to talk about **Sign-then-encrypt versus Encrypt-then-sign**, that is a very common question with cryptography, and that is not so often correctly answered. I mean there is not a simple answer, **the correct answer depends on the situation you encounter**.

First, note that Encrypt-then-sign protects against attacks based on **correlations between private key and encryption time**, when there is a live exchange between two parties. This is because when decrypting before having checked a signature, a Man-in-the-Middle attacker can make you decrypt whatever he wants you to. Then, he can measure the delay for you to decrypt, because your response will come just after you have decrypted the content he had modified (the response will often be "error" since after having decrypted the cipher text, you will see that the content is not correctly signed). So, a major rule is **never decrypt something before checking the signature**, for protocols between two parties that have a live exchange. To prevent such timing-side channel attacks, P. Gutmann from University of Auckland proposed a [drafted RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gutmann-tls-encrypt-then-mac-05), in late 2013. This RFC starts saying that: *This document describes a means of negotiating the use of the    encrypt-then-MAC security mechanism in place of TLS'/DTLS' existing MAC-then-encrypt one, which has been the subject of a number of security vulnerabilities over a period of many years*.

**Now, when you do asynchronous exchanges, like with PGP or S/MIME on top of SMTP, such a timing attack can not be done. So, you should prefer Sign-then-encrypt, for the other reasons explained by D.W.** in the thread you talked about in a comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/should-we-sign-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-sign (this is mainly to avoid the cipher text to be signed by somebody else than the emitter).

So, let's answer your question:

> Would it be acceptable in a sign-encrypt-sign (email) setup to use the same certificate for both sign operations or should one opt for two separate certificates? The encrypt operation is performed using the intended recipients public certificate.

You say this is an email context. So no timing-side channel attacks should be possible. Therefore, you should only Sign-then-encrypt.

But since you to want Sign-then-encrypt-then-sign, I think you want to avoid side channel attack for any other reason.

**So, using the same certificate (and private key) for both of the sign operations has no impact on the security level of your exchange**: as you can understand, the last sign operation is used to be sure nobody will decrypt a modified content and measure a delay, and the first sign before crypt is here to check that the cipher text can not be signed by somebody not able to decrypt. Therefore, both of these operations are not linked, so using or not the same certificate for both operations does not change anything.